# is there more elegant way to realize the filter + map spark function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to use flatMap to realize the filter() + map() , like the following code:
there are three if statement for outputting one Tuple2.
otherwise will output an empty Array[Tuple2]

Do you have more elegant way to realize this function?

```
 rddx.flatMap { case (arr: Array[String]) =>
          val url_parts = arr(1).split("/")
          if (url_parts.length > 7) {
            val pid = url_parts(4)
            val lid = url_parts(7).split("_")
            if (lid.length == 2) {
              val sid = lid(0)
              val eid = lid(1)
              if (eid.length > 0 && eid(0) == "h") {
                Array((pid, 1))
              }
              else new Array[(String, Int)](0)
            }
            else Array((pid, 1))
          }
          else new Array[(String, Int)](0)
         }
```

Comment: Is `collect` available on an `RDD` because if so, that should be what you are looking for.  The `collect` function in Scala is equivalent to `map` + `filter`.

Comment: the collect and filter+map totally different in spark. in spark, collect will read data from all remote workers... so are there other methods?

Comment: There are two variations of `collect`, one that takes no args and one that takes a `PartialFunction`, I was referring to the later of the two.  In looking at the Scala doc, that method seems to do what it would do on a normal scala collection.  Are you sure `collect` is not what you want?

Comment: yes, we could not use collect function in spark :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a for-comprehension. Granted, this will become a chain of `flatMap`, `map`, `filter`, but Spark will group those in one stage anyway, so there shouldn't be any performance penalty.

```
for {
  arr <- rddx
  url_parts = arr(1).split("/")
  if url_parts.length > 7
  pid = url_parts(4)
  lid = url_parts(7).split("_")
  if lid.length == 2
  sid = lid(0)
  eid = lid(1)
  if eid.length > 0 && eid(0) == "h"
} yield 
  Array((pid, 1))
```

Here's the output of `toDebugString` to show there's only one stage

```
scala> res.toDebugString
res2: String = 
(8) MapPartitionsRDD[7] at map at <console>:24 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[6] at filter at <console>:24 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at <console>:24 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[4] at filter at <console>:24 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at <console>:24 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at filter at <console>:24 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at <console>:24 []
 |  ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:21 []
```

Comment: I am sure you can work that out yourself from my answer. If you something is unclear in my solution, I'm happy to explain.

Answer (score 2):

*"the right tool for the job"*. 
In this case, all that parsing could be done using a regex:

```
val pidCapture = "[\\w]+/[\\w]+/[\\w]+/([\\w]+)/[\\w]+/[\\w]+/[^_]+_h[\\w]+.*".r
rdd.map(arr => arr(1)).collect { case pidCapture(pid) => (pid,1) }
```

Example on the repl, departing from urls as strings:

```
val urls = List("one/two/three/pid1/four/five/six/sid_heid", "one/two/three/pid2/four/five/six/sid_noth", "one/two/three/pid3/four/five", "one/two/three/pid4/four/five/six/sid_heid/more")
val rdd = sc.parallelize(urls)
val regex = "[\\w]+/[\\w]+/[\\w]+/([\\w]+)/[\\w]+/[\\w]+/[^_]+_h[\\w]+.*".r
val pids = rdd.collect{ case regex(pid) => (pid,1)}
val result = pids.collect()
result: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((pid1,1), (pid4,1))
```

Comment: my god=。= you are clever:-)

Comment: Or better still using scala-parser-combinators